# PHP: Get last digit of year (example: 2015 == 5)

Tags: php, unix, time, timestamp

How may I convert my function to show the last and/or the second last digit in the "Y" tag?

Here is my code:

```
<?php
$timestamp = time();     //Timestamp from server
$user_time = 1597429549; //Timestamp from database

$time = ($user_time-$timestamp); // Should be around 4 years

echo gmdate("Y m d H i s", $time); //This will output 1974 10 20 19 59 34
?>
```

How can I convert this to display time as:

**4 10 20 19 59 34** or **0004 10 20 19 59 34**

Instead of:

**1974 10 20 19 59 34**

Comment: Use `substring` and and `str_replace`

Comment: This is sounding a little like an *"XY Problem"*. Maybe start with what exactly you're trying to do, not how you think you should do it

Comment: how about using date_diff\DateTime::diff

Comment: `preg_replace` -> `^.{3}`  with `0` or an empty string.

Comment: `substr_replace($date, '000', 0, 3)`

Answer (score 5):

Use modulus operator:

```
2015 % 10 = 5
```

Comment: and if OP wants to pad it with zeroes ~ `printf('%04d', 2015 % 10)`

Answer (score 0):

**Substr** did the trick, thank you guys for pointing me in the right direction.

```
    <?php
$timestamp = time();     //Timestamp from server
$user_time = 1597429549; //Timestamp from database

$time = ($user_time-$timestamp); // Should be around 4 years

// This did the trick:

$gmdate = gmdate("y m d H i s", $time);
$rest = substr("$gmdate", -16);
?>
```